# breeze-sequelize with MSSQL possible?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, breeze, sequelize.js

Is it currently possible to connect breeze-sequelize with a MS SQL server?

According to the [doc of Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/), Sequelize does support MSSQL Server.
Though in the [breeze doc](http://breeze.github.io/doc-node-sequelize/) there is no MS SQL server listed.

I am a bit confused now. And if it is not possible, is the breeze dev team planning to impl that? Or are there alternatives to use breeze in nodejs with an MSSQL server?

Comment: in the [getting started](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/#setting-up-a-connection) section there is a reference to MSSQL. did you try to use that syntax?

Comment: with breeze i need to work with the lib `breeze-sequelize`. I need to create a SequelizeManager described in the [breeze-sequelize-docs](http://breeze.github.io/doc-node-sequelize/class-descriptions.html)

Comment: i tried to set the dialect to `mssql` though i always get the following mySql error `[Breeze] Unable to connect to mySql:Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (LocalDb)♂11.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is actually possible. It took quite some time since the breeze-sequelize documentation is not very "newb friendly".

Here is my configuration for the MS SQL server. The [tempHire](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/node/tempHire) example from the breeze samples on github was helping out a lot.

```
var dbConfig = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'secret',
    dbName: 'myDatabase'
};

var sequelizeOptions = {
    host: 'hostname',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    port: 1433
};


function createSequelizeManager() {
    var metadata = readMetadata();
    var sm = new SequelizeManager(dbConfig, sequelizeOptions);
    sm.importMetadata(metadata);

    return sm;
}
```

The only thing i could not figure out until now is how to communicate with a specific MS SQL instance on a host e.g. `localhost\MY_MSSQL_INSTANCE`.

**UPDATE**

I actually did find out how to connect to a specific named instance.

So if you want to connect to an mssql instance like `localhost\MY_MSSQL_INSTANCE`, the `sequelizeOptions` should look like the following:

```
var sequelizeOptions = {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectOptions: {
        instanceName: 'MY_MSSQL_INSTANCE'
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow! I am surprised that no one else is trying to get this to work. I love Breeze and needed to strip down an API to run on Node.js using a MSSQL backend. There is little documentation out there and your answer saved by butt. Thank you!

Comment: Yep... this answer saved the day! :-)